# How to execute a drush command with an answer to a prompt

Tags: drush, configuration, 10

When I run `drush it` to sync up my taxonomy content, I am prompted to specify the style:

```
What import style would you like?:
[0] Full
[1] Safe
[2] Force
```

Is there a way I can include my answer to this prompt in the original drush command, so the prompt is answered automatically?  I'm asking because I need to add this command to my ci/cd pipeline.

I tried it like this:

`drush it --style=0`

But that results in 'The "--style" option does not exit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the `it` command from the [Structure sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/structure_sync) module, you can use the `choice` option, e.g.

```
drush it --choice=full
```

Other options are `safe` and `force` (all lowercase).

For future reference you can run `drush <command> --help` to list the options for any command.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks.